# $n$ by $n$ matrices such that $Ax=0$ implies $Bx=0$, then what can we say about $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ideals, gre-exam

Ok, this is one of the interesting questions I encountered in my GRE Maths exam 2 weeks ago. Fix an $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ (doesn't have to be $0$), and $A$, $B$ are $n$ by $n$ matrices such that $Ax=0$ implies $Bx=0$, then what can we say about $A$ and $B$? I think the choices were: $\exists C$ an $n$ by $n$ matrices such that: 
a) $A=BC$, b) $A=CB$, c) $B=CA$, d) $B=AC$, e) $B=C^{-1}AC$.

Well, the set of matrices $D$ such that $Dx=0$ form an left ideal, but I only know what bi-ideals look like in this case. Also the wording the this question is funny, we dont know if $A$ is in the ideal or not, we just know if $A$ is in the ideal then $B$ is in the ideal.

Edit: As we discussed below, I think I misunderstood the question in the exam (although I don't have the actually paper now). $x$ is probably not fixed.

Comment: The wording is not clear. If we **fix** $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then the problem does not make sense. It would rather be "Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices such that $Ax=0$ implies $Bx=0$ ...". Please check again for the exact statement of the problem.

Comment: @i707107 Valuable feedback, but the OP mentions that it was on the GRE math exam; they won't have access to that particular test ever again.

Comment: @pjs36 Okay, I understand.

Answer (score 3):

(c) is the answer. This is a standard result.

We have $Ker A \subseteq Ker B$.  Then we may define $C$ on $Im A$ by:
$$
C: Im A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, \ \ C( Ax) = Bx.
$$

This is well defined because $Ax=Ay$ implies $Bx=By$.

We may extend $C$ to the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then we have $B=CA$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I don't know why I thought x is fixed in the exam. It may just said let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$... But yeah, you are exactly right in this case, define $C|_{ImA}=B$, then extend to $KerA+ImA$, and it is well defined because $B(KerA)=0$ (which is i think exactly what you did).

Comment: I would still stick to writing $C(Ax)=Bx$ because $C|_{Im A} = B$ will mean that $C(Ax) = B(Ax)$.

Comment: Also, $dim Ker A + dim Im A = n$, but this does not imply that $Ker A + Im A = \mathbb{R}^n$. The way to extend $C$ is just by throwing in few more basis elements outside $Im A$ and defining to be $0$ on those ones.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer: (c)

$Ax=0$ is equivalent to "$x$ is perpendicular to all the rows of $A$". Hence, 
the statement
$$
\forall x\in\mathbb R^n (Ax=0\Longrightarrow Bx=0)
$$
tells us that the space spanned by the rows of $B$ is a subspace of the space spanned by the rows of $A$. Hence, each row $b_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, the of $B$ is a linear combination of the rows of $A$. Thus, $b_i=c_iA$, where $c_i$ is a vector of the same dimension.

Therefore, $B=CA$, where $C$ is the matrix with rows $c_1,\ldots,c_n$.

Comment: I agree on most of this, but going from the statement $Ax=0 \Longrightarrow Bx=0$ to row space of $B$ is a subspace of row space of $A$ is a bit unclear. Would you please explain more on this?

Comment: But, this argument is useful if $Im A \subseteq Im B$ is given. Then we would use the same argument as yours on columns, to prove that $A=BC$ for some $n\times n$ matrix $C$.